# Почему delegate обнуляется?

Tags: objective-c, делегаты

Есть 2  UITextField, которые объединены в IBOutletCollection. Есть метод, в котором на эти 2 TextField навешиваются UIPickerView. На сами PickerView устанавливается delegate, методы которого реализуются в классе CurrencyPickerView:

```
-(void) configureValutePicker {
    for (UITextField *textField in self.valutePickerTextFields) {

        CurrencyPickerView *cpv = [[CurrencyPickerView alloc] initWithData: self.parserResult.result Textfield: self.activeTextField];
        UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];

        pickerView.delegate = cpv;
        pickerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        textField.inputAccessoryView = pickerView;
        textField.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

В чем проблема: проблема в том что на 1 итерации к первому полю вешается пикер, а на пикер устанавливается делегат. В дебаггере это хорошо видно (`_delegate    CurrencyPickerView *    0x7fbbb2f072c0  0x00007fbbb2f072c0`). Затем на 2 итерации, если посмотреть дебаггер, то видно, что на прошлом текстовом поле у пикера делегат уже: `_delegate   id  0x0 0x0000000000000000`

В итоге, собственно, методы (titleForRow и прочие) не вызываются из класса..

Comment: я так понимаю у вас cpv удаляется из памяти, как только приведенный метод закончил работу

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Если так, каким образом это можно предотвратить?

Comment: хранить cpv в переменной инстанса

Comment: Благодарю, помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю у вас cpv удаляется из памяти, как только приведенный метод закончил работу, вам надо его сохранять в переменной инстанса.